# ssh connection taking a long time from one workstation

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to connect to a rasperry pi which is on my office network over SSH.  From one workstation in my office, it connects super quick, but from my laptop it just hangs when trying to connect for sometimes minutes before I get the password prompt.

I'm using ssh from macOS on my laptop..

My ssh_config config looks like this:

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

And the relevent option for ~/.ssh/config looks like this:

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    UseKeychain yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The verbose output from ssh looks like this, so it appears to be hanging when trying to connect

```
$ ssh pi@pi.local -v
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/<>/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/<>/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to pi.local port 22.
```

Is there anything which may be causing this?  Also is there any way to "clear the cache" or something like that with SSH which may mitigate an issue like this?  I have used exactly this laptop with exactly this Rpi and ssh config in the past with no issues.

Comment: when connected how long does it take to resolv IP your comming from ? or similar IP ?

Comment: How would I test that with a similar IP?  Since today I can't get it to connect at all

Comment: I tought It would connect after a long time, therefore bad or slow IP to name translation would have been to blame. now it's more clear you don't have IP route from home. can you `ping pi.local` ? `traceroute pi.local` ? if yes can you copy/**edit to remove public home & office IP**/paste result ?

Comment: both from home and office, along with result from `ip r s` (ip route show)

Comment: this is when I am connecting while connected to the office network

Comment: could this be related to DNS issues? Either forward dns or reverse dns? It's not unusual for timeout like this to be related to resover issues.

Comment: how would I know if it's a DNS issue or resolve that?  Is there any way to just "clear the cache" or something like that?  As I said it was working perfectly before